# Getting table from HTML file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
game_link = "http://espn.go.com/nba/playbyplay?gameId=400579510&period=0"
game_source = urlopen(game_link)
game_html = game_source.read()
game_source.close();
row = BeautifulSoup(game_html, "html.parser")
pieces = list(row.children)
```

I need to get game log rows from above link but above my code gives me whol HTML text how can I extract tables and turn them into single rowns (pieces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `BeautifulSoup.findAll` and supply the tag and any other attributes you may know about the tags you are looking for. After looking at the page it looks like you're looking for all `<tr>` tags with the class `even`. So you could use `soup.findAll("tr", attrs = {"class": "even"})`. For example.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

game_link = "http://espn.go.com/nba/playbyplay?gameId=400579510&period=0"
game_source = urllib.request.urlopen(game_link)
game_html = game_source.read()
game_source.close();
soup = BeautifulSoup(game_html, "html.parser")
# find all instances of a row with class "even"
rows = soup.findAll("tr", attrs = {"class": "even"})
for row in rows:
    // do work
    print(row)
```

You would still need to parse the html for each row. The following is a very "crude" example.

```
def parse_row(row):
    cols = row.findAll("td") # get each column in the row
    # ignore timeouts, this is just an example
    if len(cols) < 4:
        return None
    else:
        return {
                "time": cols[0].get_text(),
                "team1": cols[1].get_text(),
                "score": cols[2].get_text(),
                "team2": cols[3].get_text()
               }

parsed_rows = []
for row in rows:
    parsed = parse_row(row)
    if parsed:
        parsed_rows.append(parsed)
```

Comment: but `list(rows.children)` gives me error that it is not BS object

Comment: If you're referring to the code listed in my answer `rows` is the result from `findAll` which returns a list of [Tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) objects. So if you want the `children` attribute of each row you could do something like `[x.children for x in rows]`

Comment: sorry but that is giving my this kind of list `[<list_iterator at 0xf5faf586a0>,
 <list_iterator at 0xf5faf587b8>,
 <list_iterator at 0xf5faf589b0>,
 <list_iterator at 0xf5fadf9048>,
 <list_iterator at 0xf5fadf9080>]`

Comment: Yep, [children](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down) yields and iterator. See the documentation above. Honestly, I wouldn't bother with `children`. I'd use `findAll` on the `Tag` object. I'll edit the answer to reflect this..